# Error loading shared library libssl.so.10 on Alpine docker

Tags: docker, openssl, alpine-linux

I am running aerospike client which requires library libssl.so.10. Its unable to find so. I am trying to run on [this base docker image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/node/14.15.1-alpine/images/sha256-05a2f563ff66492dbe3c82cb482d6c1bbaecefcac4d42bd3744c7693028c9e44?context=explore). Its base is alpine 3.11. It tried installing libressl but still it was unable to find.

I tried finding the file in my file system
`file . -name *libssl*`
The output dint have  `libssl.so.10` file.
Which openssl/libssl has the `libssl.so.10` file supported by alpine 3.11?

Comment: I cannot see that the image is trying to install libssl? You could try to role your own and add `RUN apk add libressl-dev` and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: tried installing libssl-dev and  openssl-dev but none of them contained the exact file needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using incompatible versions of Aerospike and Alpine (both are obsolete, however).

`libssl.so.10` should be an alias of `libssl.so.1.0.0` (see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/339371/160225) that suggests the creation of a link), but v1.0.0 is obsolete so commands like `apk` (in Alpine) or `apt` (in Debian) install at least v1.1.

I don't know why you are using obsolete versions and whether you can update them or not; however, generally speaking, I would suggest to upgrade both Aerospike and the Node image to the latest version or, at least, Aerospike to a version that uses `libssl` v1.1.

As an alternative, I have found [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/688289/265691) that provides a link to manually download `libssl` v1.0.0 on Debian and I have tried the installation in `node:14.15.1-buster-slim` (the same version of Node that you are using but Debian-based):

```
docker run -it --rm node:14.15.1-buster-slim bash

apt update
apt install wget dialog apt-utils -y
wget http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20190501T215844Z/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.28-10_amd64.deb
wget http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20170705T160707Z/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2l-1%7Ebpo8%2B1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i multiarch-support*.deb
dpkg -i libssl1.0.0*.deb
```

Then, if I execute `find  -iname 'libssl*'`, I get:

```
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
./usr/share/doc/libssl1.1
./usr/share/doc/libssl1.0.0
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.1:amd64.list
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.1:amd64.md5sums
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.1:amd64.postinst
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.1:amd64.postrm
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.1:amd64.shlibs
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.1:amd64.symbols
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.1:amd64.templates
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.1:amd64.triggers
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.0.0:amd64.list
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.0.0:amd64.md5sums
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.0.0:amd64.postrm
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.0.0:amd64.postinst
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.0.0:amd64.shlibs
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.0.0:amd64.symbols
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.0.0:amd64.templates
```

So now you can create a link:

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10
```

and try to execute Aerospike.  Obviously you have to put these instructions in a `Dockerfile`.  Let us know if it works.

Comment: I can use `node:14.15.1-buster-slim` as the base image. I will try this and let you know. Cannot update the version of Aerospike client nor can I update node version as of now